# Display a URL on changing the select option in JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I need to display a URL in a jsp page when changing the select option.

```
<form:select path="type" name="type" id="type" onChange="SelectType();">
<form:option value="Select type">Select type</form:option>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
```

In the above code, when i change the option value, a URL corresponding to the value need to be displayed below the options. The URL should be urlname/type?value=---.

That URL should display a pop up window. I am directly displaying the pop up window on changing the type. I need to display a URL and on clicking the URL I need to display the pop up window. The `SelectType();` function displays the popup window in my case.

Comment: and where you have stored those url?

Comment: By "displaying a URL", I guess you mean "displaying a link". What's your question? What have you tried? What's the problem?

Comment: yes, I need to display a link. I directly displayed the page instead of displaying the link